# Do I pay taxes on investment income in a traditional IRA?

Tags: united-states, taxes, ira, investing

I have a traditional IRA. I converted it to that during a rollover from a prior employer's 401k, because I wanted to do the investing myself. I am not making regular contributions to this IRA. Do I have to report any investment income (or losses) from this account, and are they taxable as income?

I have not received any 1099 for this IRA account from my broker, whereas I did receive 1099s for my regular investment account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. And No. 
If it's purely pretax money, the growth is tax deferred, and when the money is withdrawn, it's all taxed at your then marginal rate. For now, it's not part of the annual reporting.